# Show that ideal $(X,Y)\subset \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ is not invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I think I have to proceed by contradiction, but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestion?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If  it were invertible, it would be a projective ideal, hence its localisations at every maximal ideal would be free and thus principal.